# complex sql statement to different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table which has 4 fields:

```
indexID
UserID
text_1
IsFinal
```

This table may have multiple values for each `UserID`, and `IsFinal` field can have only a single value 1 or 0.

What I'm trying to do is to make a select statement which will return the user IDs if `IsFinal` only equal 0. The problem there may be multiple records for the same userID, some having `IsFinal` equal to 0 and only 1 with `IsFinal` equal to 1.

My problem here is this: for every `UserID`, if it has a record with `Isfinal = 1`, I want to ignore all records with the same `UserID`, otherwise I want to return its records. I don't know if that can be done by SQL statement only or not.

Comment: A 5-line sentence is not easy to read and understand :-(

Comment: I tried to rephrase your question to make it a bit clearer. Please review my edit to verify that I didn't change your meaning. Feel free to roll it back if something's wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want an *anti-join*, i.e. you first need to establish which user IDs have `IsFinal = 1`, then use that result set to return all user IDs *not* in that list.

There are various ways to implement an anti-join.

1. `NOT IN`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM atable
   WHERE UserID NOT IN (
     SELECT UserID
     FROM atable
     WHERE IsFinal = 1
   );
   ```
2. `NOT EXISTS`:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM atable t1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM atable t2
     WHERE t1.UserID = t2.UserID
       AND t2.IsFinal = 1
   );
   ```
3. `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL`:

   a)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM atable t1
     LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT *
       FROM atable
       WHERE IsFinal = 1
     ) t2 ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
   WHERE t2.UserID IS NULL;
   ```

   b)

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM atable t1
     LEFT JOIN atable t2
       ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID AND t2.IsFinal = 1
   WHERE t2.UserID IS NULL;
   ```

It may so happen that they will be equally efficient in your database, but it still may be a good idea to test each of them to at least avoid ending up with one that performs worse than the others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM translations a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT UserID FROM translations WHERE IsFinal = 1) b
        ON a.UserID = b.UserID
WHERE IsFinal = 0;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM translations WHERE isFinal = 1) b ON a.Aya = b.Aya WHERE isFinal = ' at line 3

Comment: @Omesh: this is `SELECT` not `SELCT`

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( not tested )

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 USING(indexID)
WHERE t1.IsFinal <>1
GROUP BY t1.UserID
```