# Select rows in master table which have NO join in subtable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: result (master) and confirmation(sub):

```
CREATE TABLE result
(
  result_id serial NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT result_pkey PRIMARY KEY (result_id)
)

CREATE TABLE confirmation
(
  confirmation_id serial NOT NULL,
  result_id integer
  CONSTRAINT confirmation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (confirmation_id),
  CONSTRAINT confirmation_result_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (result_id)
      REFERENCES result (result_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I'm able to find all results having a confirmation:

```
SELECT 
result.result_id,
confirmation.confirmation_id
FROM Result
JOIN confirmation ON confirmation.result_id = result.result_id
```

But I need it vice-versa - all results still without a single confirmation.

Comment: To clarify, do you need the result set to include both matching and non-matching rows or just the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM confirmation WHERE confirmation.result_id = result.result_id)
```

Comment: +1: great! works! Such a tricky way without a JOIN? I would never get it myself :-)

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: The concept itself is called an *anti-join* (sometimes *anti-semi-join*) and [has several implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11758854), one of which does involve the `JOIN` keyword.